# How to make a duplex 7 segment display

Tags: ac, 7segmentdisplay

I have built the circuit below and have been using a 7 segment display which is meant to be designed to work with the circuit. However there is no clear diagrams showing which wire on the display connects to what pin on the chip. So I painstakingly worked out where each wire should go, but the display does not work. Would it perhaps be easier than trying to get the connections correct by trial and error to build my own display?

[image]

Comment: IMO the pins clearly identify to which segments they are to be connected, for instance pin 8 to 10-minutes digit, anodes of segments b and g. Which pins that are of the display depends on the display, for that you should consult its datasheet.

Comment: there is no datasheet for the display

Comment: Get a display with a data sheet.

Comment: Could you recommend a display that will work with this circuit and has a data sheet Leon Heller?

Comment: If you have a display without a datasheet, how can you say that it is designed to work with this chip? Anyway, you can get a 5V or so supply and a 1k resistor, and find out the display pinout for yourself. Takes some time, but definitely can be done.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done I know the display should work because the person I purchased it off told me it would work with the circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there should not be problems with this circuit. Everything is written here For connection. In the LM8560 it's written something like in Pin7 a&f, a=>segment a, f=>segment f. MIN=>Minutes digits, HR=>Hour digits.
Choosing your Display, i think that you can you can look at any duplex display but it just use the `CATHODE COMMON` as well and you should not ask yourself why isn't working !

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly wire a display that is not internally multiplexed in any way you want, including duplexing, however I don't see why it would be any better than a display that is designed to work with that chip.

There are single, dual and quad digits (at least) that are so wired, but check before buying to make sure they're not internally multiplexed. One hint is the number of  pins- if there are 9 pins per digit (or perhaps 10) then they are probably not internally multiplexed, and it's worth checking the datasheet  for the details.